# In Xaml, how to make a symbling's height depend on another's dynamically calculated height

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a DataTemplate with a three columns arranged in a grid where I would like to make the height of the entire grid dependent on the height of the first column's content. These are the solutions I've tried but I may not have done it right...

1. Grid.Height = {Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=Height}
2. Column1.Height = Column2.Height = {Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=Height}

Only (2) works if the height of Column0 is hard code, but that is not what is required. It is weird that (1) does not work since the measure/arrange Xaml display process should seem to allow for it.

The upshot is that it seems the height of a column is always the height of the container of the Grid itself. As a result, it seems impossible to do something as elegant as this...

```
<Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Column0">
    ...
  </Grid>
  <Grid 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Height="{Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=Height}"
    >
    ...
  </Grid>
  <Grid 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Height="{Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=Height}"
    >
    ...
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

or

```
<Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=Height}">
  <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Column0">...</Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="1">...</Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="2">...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=Column0,Path=ActualHeight}"
```

The "Height" properties are merely "suggested" heights and are determined after the measure and arrange phases, it seems.

Note: both the first and second approaches will work, though the behaviours are slightly different, though it may be due to the specific control used for the child column. Essentially, the child grid of, Column0, will respect the height of it's container and so will not report a change in it's actual height until the it can't help it (one of it's row has expanded too far for it to shrink the others to accommodate it). This is not reasonable behaviour for "ActualHeight".